# LINQ: Why does Expression.Call() reference the Db when CreateQuery() does as well?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

So I'm trying to optimize a query that does a text search on 1000s of rows and displays 100s of them. To do so, I'm trying to understand some code from Microsoft's 101 Sample Queries (found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Sample-Queries-13a42a54)).

Here is the code I wish to understand:

```
    [Category("Advanced")]
    [Title("Dynamic query - Where")]
    [Description("This sample builds a query dynamically to filter for Customers in London.")]
    public void LinqToSqlAdvanced02()
    {
        IQueryable<Customer> custs = db.Customers;
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "c");
        Expression right = Expression.Constant("London");
        Expression left = Expression.Property(param, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("City"));
        Expression filter = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        Expression pred = Expression.Lambda(filter, param);

        Expression expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new Type[] { typeof(Customer) }, Expression.Constant(custs), pred);
        IQueryable<Customer> query = db.Customers.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery<Customer>(expr);
        ObjectDumper.Write(query);
    }
```

So...I realize this is esoteric, but why does Expression.Call() need the DbSet reference it's passed to CreateQuery as `<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is why the third parameter (array of types) is needed in `Expression.Call` because if you did it through code, you'd only have to do this:

```
custs.Where(pred);
```

The reason why the code works without the generic parameter is because of *implicit typing*, where the *compiler* translates that automatically to:

```
custs.Where<Customer>(pred);
```

After it translates it, the actual bytecode contains the call with the generics specified.  When you build the `Expression`, you don't have all the niceties like implicit typing, so you have to specify exactly what gets called.